# AuthUI: task is marked successful but user is not being created

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Okay, so I have some code that I remember working a while ago, idk if something changed or so, basically my auth activity returns an OK result but user is not registered nor logged in.

This is the login activity:

```
fun login() {
    val providers = arrayListOf(
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build()
    )

    val layout = AuthMethodPickerLayout
        .Builder(R.layout.firebase_auth)
        .setEmailButtonId(R.id.loginMailBT)
        .setFacebookButtonId(R.id.loginFbBT)
        .build()

    startActivityForResult(
        AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(layout)
            .setTheme(R.style.Theme_taniechlanie_AuthUI)
            .build(),
        loginRC
    )
}
```

And this is the result listener:

```
//Login
    if (requestCode == loginRC) {
        val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && auth.currentUser != null) {
            if (response!!.isNewUser) {
                userViewModel.login(auth.currentUser, true, object : RequestListener {
                    override fun onComplete(resultCode: Int) {
                        if (resultCode != RequestListener.SUCCESS) {
                            longToast(applicationContext, getString(R.string.toast_error))
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        } else if (response != null) {
            val message =
                if (response.error?.errorCode == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK)
                    getString(R.string.err_no_connection)
                else
                    getString(R.string.error, response.error?.errorCode.toString())
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                message,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    }
```

Also some ppl managed to create an account without a problem

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo no errors or even warns, the code behaves as if the user was being created, but it is not